# http_authenticable? error in Rails 3 - set_current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Here you can see the error message along with the my application controller file - that is referrenced in the error.

https://gist.github.com/812160

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this or how I can further get to the bottom of it?

Comment: Close this question because the gist has been deleted and the question is worthless without the information that was in the gist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had another plugin that was messing things up. AASM for those that are interested.